# GEF : How to programmatically create a connection?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef, eclipse-gmf

I would like to create an Eclipse cheatsheet which explain how to create two tiles and connect them.

I successfully coded a command which create the two tiles but not the command to create a connection between the two tiles (i.e : source  and target `EditPart`) in my GEF `DiagramEditPart`.

Does someone know how to do this or have a code example with explanations to provide ?

Thank you all in advance !

Answer (score 1):

To learn GEF I found it very helpful to go through this [GEF tutorial](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ip/resources/GEF/GEF_Tutorial_2up.pdf). However, it does not cover connections but [here](http://gefhowto.blogspot.de/2010/01/adding-connections-to-gef-environment.html) is an extension of this tutorial which exactly describes this. There is also a great blog series about creating a GEF editor which handles connections [here](https://www.vainolo.com/2011/07/13/creating-a-gef-editor-%E2%80%93-part-9-connections/).

Comment: Yes, great blog series :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at the logics/shapes example that provided by GEF. I found those sample code together with [vainolo series](https://www.vainolo.com/tutorials/gef-tutorials/) are the most helpful